# How to redirect to parent model after edit of child in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have Request model. I have two types of requests, parent and child. One parent Request can have many child Requests but child can have only one parent.

Suppose I am editing some child Request. After update I want to redirect to its parent Request. 
Here is my code:

```html
 def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @request.update(request_params)
        format.html { redirect_to request_path(params[:parent_request_id]) , notice: 'Request was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @request }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @request.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

so i redirect to request_path(params[:parent_request_id]). 
where parent_request_id is defined in hidden_field inside form, and passed through url.
Inspecting in browser showed me my hidden field in form with a value set:

```html
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="request[parent_request_id]" id="request_parent_request_id">
```

But I got error:

```html
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"requests", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Comment: You have to do `params[:request][:parent_request_id]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it *almost* right.

Check the params being sent on the terminal when you submit the form. You will see that all parameters sent to the update action, including `[:parent_request_id`], are wrapped in `[:request]` .

In order to reach that param, you need to put this:

```
 params[:request][:parent_request_id]
```

Also, look at the error - it tells you that the value is `nil` there, which means that nothing went through. This means that a) You forgot to permit that parameter b) You mispelled it/didn't write the correct value.